# Errno 30 read-only file system

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

I was coding a program for my raspberry pi pico. I wanted it to run a program as soon as it was plugged in. However, it should also register in a file called logs that something has happened.

Then I got the error. I'm from Austria, so it's in German, but it means, that I have no permission the write in that file. Can somebody please help me? (German error code: Schreibgeschützte Dateisystem)
Here is the Code:

```
print("Registering the process..")

logs = open("logs.txt", "a")

logs.write("Operation has been saved")

logs. Close()
```

bb

Comment: Why do you think you have permission to write to that file?  Why do you think this program has that permission?

Comment: This code tries to open the file in the current directory, which is on a disk that is not writable.

Comment: Either change the code to write the file in some other directory, or change the setup of your Pi so that disk is writable.

Comment: you can check permission by running `ls -l log.txt`

Comment: @Hackaholic That won't do any good.  The problem is that the _entire disk_ is not writable.

Comment: oh ok, may be can run as sudo user or root